# mule flow http to wmq fails with classnotfound error - ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException

Tags: mule, ibm-mq, mule-component, anypoint-studio

Learning to use Mule, and trying to connect to WebSphere MQ. I have a flow as

http -> payload -> logger -> WMQ.

This is a one way message, the static msg on the payload will be PUT to the queue.
I have configured WMQ global Element. Added MQ library "com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar" as my MQ client version is MQ 8.0.0.2

There is no error in the flow, but at runtime while deploying it fails.

below is the error I get during deployment/runtime.

```
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:06,630 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultMuleDomain: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New domain 'default'                                     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:06,630 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultMuleDomain: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing domain 'default'                            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:06,630 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started domain 'default'                                 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:06,630 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.ArtifactArchiveInstaller: Exploding a Mule artifact archive: file:/C:/Users/xxxxxxx/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/http-jms-tutorial.zip
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:06,739 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New app 'http-jms-tutorial'                              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:06,739 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader: [http-jms-tutorial] Loading the following jars:
=============================
file:/C:/Users/xxxxxxx/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/http-jms-tutorial/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar
=============================

INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:06,833 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing app 'http-jms-tutorial'                     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:07,051 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:07,160 [main] org.mule.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Starting discovery of extensions
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:07,301 [main] org.mule.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Discovered 1 extensions
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:07,301 [main] org.mule.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension validation (version 3.7)
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:07,363 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@158a3b2e: startup date [Fri May 27 15:03:07 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:08,627 [main] org.mule.config.spring.processors.NoDevkitInjectorProcessor: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
WARN  2016-05-27 15:03:09,579 [main] org.mule.module.ognl.expression.OgnlExpressionEvaluator: OGNL module is deprecated and will be removed in Mule 4.0. Use MEL expressions instead.
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:09,954 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising connector: WMQ
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,126 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising model: _muleSystemModel
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,126 [main] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Initialising flow: http-jms-tutorialFlow
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,126 [main] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: Initialising exception listener: org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy@4d18b73a
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,173 [main] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager: Initialising service: http-jms-tutorialFlow.stage1
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,204 [main] org.mule.util.journal.TransactionJournal: Using files for tx logs C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AnypointStudio\workspace\.mule\.\.mule\http-jms-tutorial\queue-tx-log\tx1.log and C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AnypointStudio\workspace\.mule\.\.mule\http-jms-tutorial\queue-tx-log\tx2.log
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,204 [main] org.mule.util.journal.TransactionJournal: Using files for tx logs C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AnypointStudio\workspace\.mule\.\.mule\http-jms-tutorial\queue-xa-tx-log\tx1.log and C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AnypointStudio\workspace\.mule\.\.mule\http-jms-tutorial\queue-xa-tx-log\tx2.log
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,454 [main] org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder: Configured Mule using "org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder" with configuration resource(s): "[ConfigResource{resourceName='C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AnypointStudio\workspace\.mule\apps\http-jms-tutorial\http-jms-tutorial.xml'}]"
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,454 [main] org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder: Configured Mule using "org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder" with configuration resource(s): "[ConfigResource{resourceName='C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AnypointStudio\workspace\.mule\apps\http-jms-tutorial\http-jms-tutorial.xml'}]"
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,454 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Starting app 'http-jms-tutorial'                         +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,454 [main] org.mule.util.queue.QueueXaResourceManager: Starting ResourceManager
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,454 [main] org.mule.util.queue.QueueXaResourceManager: Started ResourceManager
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,501 [main] org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListenerConfig: Listening for requests on http://0.0.0.0:8081
ERROR 2016-05-27 15:03:10,532 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:175) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.findClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:119) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.getConstructor(ClassUtils.java:583) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.getConstructor(ClassUtils.java:570) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:456) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:510) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:482) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.WebSphereMQConnector.getDefaultConnectionFactory(WebSphereMQConnector.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.createConnectionFactory(JmsConnector.java:319) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.WebSphereMQConnector.createConnectionFactory(WebSphereMQConnector.java:223) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.WebSphereMQConnector.doConnect(WebSphereMQConnector.java:202) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1603) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:63) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1668) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.connect(JmsConnector.java:466) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:443) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:294) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:98) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:93) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:163) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.3.jar:?]
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,532 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Disposing app 'http-jms-tutorial'                        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,532 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBroker
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,532 [main] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Disposing flow: http-jms-tutorialFlow
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,532 [main] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager: Disposing service: http-jms-tutorialFlow.stage1
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,532 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing model: _muleSystemModel
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,548 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing connector: WMQ
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,688 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Closing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@158a3b2e: startup date [Fri May 27 15:03:07 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,891 [main] org.mule.DefaultMuleContext: 
**********************************************************************
* Application "http-jms-tutorial" shut down normally on: 5/27/16     *
* 3:03 PM                                                            *
* Up for: 0 days, 0 hours, 0 mins, 0.437 sec                         *
**********************************************************************
ERROR 2016-05-27 15:03:10,938 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'http-jms-tutorial', see below +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:156) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:98) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:93) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:163) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.3.jar:?]
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: WebSphereMQConnector
{
  name=WMQ
  lifecycle=initialise
  this=67e13bd0
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=false
  supportedProtocols=[wmq]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:248) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:294) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSRuntimeException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.getConstructor(ClassUtils.java:583) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.getConstructor(ClassUtils.java:570) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:456) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:510) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:482) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.WebSphereMQConnector.getDefaultConnectionFactory(WebSphereMQConnector.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.createConnectionFactory(JmsConnector.java:319) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.WebSphereMQConnector.createConnectionFactory(WebSphereMQConnector.java:223) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.WebSphereMQConnector.doConnect(WebSphereMQConnector.java:202) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1603) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:63) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1668) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.connect(JmsConnector.java:466) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:443) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:294) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:175) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.findClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:119) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.getConstructor(ClassUtils.java:583) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.getConstructor(ClassUtils.java:570) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:456) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:510) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:482) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.WebSphereMQConnector.getDefaultConnectionFactory(WebSphereMQConnector.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.createConnectionFactory(JmsConnector.java:319) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.WebSphereMQConnector.createConnectionFactory(WebSphereMQConnector.java:223) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.WebSphereMQConnector.doConnect(WebSphereMQConnector.java:202) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1603) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:63) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1668) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.connect(JmsConnector.java:466) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:443) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:294) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 14 more
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:10,938 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-05-27 15:03:11,001 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.StartupSummaryDeploymentListener: 
**********************************************************************
*              - - + DOMAIN + - -               * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* default                                       * DEPLOYED           *
**********************************************************************

*******************************************************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *
*******************************************************************************************************
* http-jms-tutorial                             * default                        * FAILED             *
*******************************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

MQ 8.0 is not supported as of now. try MQ 7 library.